# vertical-align is not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know it's quite annoying, seems that vertical-align in CSS is common pitfall but I really need your help.

I want the text to be always be in "middle" vertical position left to the image (image test.gif has different dimensions)

I have such structure of html elements (unfortunately I can't change it due to system restrictions)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"> 
        <img alt="some text" src="http://localhost/test.gif">
    </div> 
    <div  class="source">some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {clear: both;}
.logo {float: left;}
.source { float: left;line-height: 16px;}
```

Spent 1.5 hours and no luck. Tried to apply vertical align to different elements with different positioning, etc...Please help!

Comment: So.. you **cannot** change any HTML?

Comment: @JoshC Yes you're right, I can't change anything in html

Comment: I know this is resolved, but another option is to change the line-height of the text to match the height of the image on the left. Note that this will only work if you know that height, and is static. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tJrSs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE7, try this:

```
.wrapper { display: table; }
.logo { display: table-cell; }
.source { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Basically, tables give you the option to vertically align to the middle, and by making your `div`s act like a table, we can mimic that option.

Comment: You might want to set up a jsfiddle so we can help you more. Also, try adding the display: table-cell to your .logo div as well.

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sq7kZ/, also I tried to add  display: table-cell to .logo but no result. Thanks for your willingness to help. Maybe you have some more ideas how to do this?

Comment: Get rid of the float: lefts and that fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

A common issue but is explained well here: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

**Key Points**

Specify the parent container as `position:relative` or `position:absolute`

Specify a fixed height on the child container.

Set position:absolute and `top:50%` on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.

Set `margin-top:-yy` where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myoutercontainer { position:relative }
    #myinnercontainer { position:absolute; top:50%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em }
</style>

...

<div id="myoutercontainer">
    <div id="myinnercontainer">
        <p>Hey look! I'm vertically centered!</p>
        <p>How sweet is this?!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you can't change your HTML - so not sure if much use.

Comment: This depends on always knowing the height of your text. For a dynamic solution, this would be challenging.